# BIRT limit X series per chart like in JasperReports, drawing multiple charts

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, birt

I'm using BIRT right now to display some charts. I need to display a bar chart based on scripted data. If there is too much data, then the chart X series get very compact.

I want to **limit the number of X series displayed on a chart**, let's say to 5, then the **next 5 to draw on another chart and so on**. This **is possible in JasperReports by using nested groups and resetting the chart on a group** event. I can't achieve this in BIRT.

Is this possible in BIRT?

P.S. I need to obtain what is on top of the image below, like in Jasper. What I can with BIRT is on the bottom-right

[image: I need to obtain what is on top, like in Jasper. What I can with BIRT right now is on the bottom-right]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible:

1. Add a Table item to the report, with the appropriate dataset.
2. Add a group to the table, to restrict the number of series to no more than 5 series per group (ie. grouped in the same way as the nested groups would be set up in your JasperReports.)
3. Delete all rows from the table object **except** the group footer.
4. Add a graph to the group footer (by dragging from the Palette) and set up columns, values and series as normal.

No resetting of the chart on a group event should be necessary, since the grouping is already done within the table object.

Comment: Well, it seems that this solution might work, but how do I do the 2nd step? How do I restrict the number of series per group. For example I have entries, and some of them have the city in common. I want to group by city, and to show the number of entries for no more than 5 cities on a chart. How do I do this? Can you provide a simple example (Group On condition, or how to create this restricted group). Thank you!

Comment: @XMight: How would you do this in Jasper? Is your datasource an RDBMS (such as Oracle, Postgres, etc) and if so, which one?

Comment: Well, such an example exists in the samples in jasperreports project. Anyway, my data is a custom data source (implement JRDataSource) and I do the following:
1. group on the city (`$F{the_city}`)
2. outer group on the following condition: 

`Integer.valueOf(Integer.valueOf($V{CityCount} - 1) / 5)`
3. CityCount is the count of running groups

I don't know how to group like that in BIRT.

Comment: In jasper the outer group uses the result of the inner group. This is not true for BIRT however.

Comment: @XMight: Is your datasource an RDBMS (such as Oracle, Postgres, etc) and if so, which one?

Comment: Currently no database, but it will be Mongo DB and MySQL. But I don't think this matters at all, because my data will reach BIRT through a scripted data set, that will use an interface to get everything. I return right now data like that:
  `if ("the_city".equals(fieldName)) {
   value = data[index][0];
  } else if ("id".equals(fieldName)) {
   value = data[index][1];
  } else if ("name".equals(fieldName)) {
   value = data[index][2];
  } else if ("street".equals(fieldName)) {
   value = data[index][3];
  }`
in the override method `public Object getFieldValue(JRField field)`

Comment: The reason I asked is that it is fairly simple to set up a group count in most versions of SQL; however, it is not so easy in MySQL.

Comment: I can count the number of groups in BIRT, using JavaScript variables, however I can't group the obtained cities groups again, 5 for a chart, 5 for another chart and so on, that's what I need. You mentioned in the second step, but how to do this? Theoretically I know that I need to do this, but how practically in BIRT?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in BIRT alone, but you could do it using a subquery in MySQL: `select ..., (select count(distinct City) from MyTable t2 where t2.City <= t1.City) as CityCount from MyTable t1`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8447/discussion-between-xmight-and-mark-bannister)